# Determining when functions allocate memory in C++

Tags: c++, c, memory, memory-leaks

So one major problem I have is determining whether a given function in C/C++ does memory allocation or not. I frequently work with external libraries, some of which have functions that return pointers to new objects. Is there some basic design paradigm or convention that will let me know ahead of time if something allocates memory?

It would seem like any function that returns a pointer to a new object must be allocating memory, but this does not always seem to be the case. For example, fopen does not

Edit: To be clear, I don't have access to the source code so I can't just check if it uses new or malloc, ect.

Comment: Most libraries have functions to delete objects that they create.  I'm not sure of the motivation of your question.  You can use valgrind to find memory leaks.

Comment: There's no portable way to determine if a pointer was obtained from `new`, `malloc`, or automatic storage. If the library doesn't document who is responsible for releasing the memory then it's junk.

Answer (score 3):

Read the documentation of all libraries you use. They should tell you if certain things should be freed.

Comment: Some of the libraries are not well-documented

Comment: Then I would suggest using the library functions in a little test program WITHOUT freeing memory, and then use valgrind to see if any memory had leaked. If so, then you need to free it in your actual program.

Comment: @SamBryant - don't use poorly documented libraries. You can't design good software if you don't know what your components are doing.

Answer (score 2):

If they documented the libraries well (as all the built in libraries are), then it should state something along the lines of "caller must free" in the post condition, sub section side effects of the function.

Answer (score 0):

For C++ anything that calls new or new [] allocates memory. So a function does if it calls those or calls any function (that calls any function.... and so on) that calls new.

The same in C except the calls are malloc, calloc and family.

Comment: Yeah I know, but since these are external libraries, I usually don't have access to the source code and sometimes they are not well documented

Comment: Well you can use a tool like valgrind or a header file that replaces new and delete and get this to enumerate all the memory allocation and free calls.

Comment: @DavidElliman: It seriously looks like you didn't correctly understand either the question nor the comments on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The best, or at least simplest, solution is the documentation, of course.

But, if you want to be sure that the function doesn't use malloc, you wrap malloc (and its friends calloc, realloc and eventually free) to gather some stats.

Writing wrappers is quiet simple, at least if can use dlsym(3) (sorry I don't know the windows way for that), here is the code for malloc:

```
void *malloc(size_t s) {
  // Retrieve the pointer to the libc's malloc
  // I use a static var to avoid time penality
  static void* (*real_malloc)(size_t) = NULL;
  if (!real_malloc) real_malloc = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"malloc");
  stat.nmalloc += 1; // count malloc calls
  stat.smalloc += s; // count malloced size
  // You can also directly print malloc's parameters
  // but you first need to check that stdio functions
  // doesn't use malloc, or write your own printer
  return real_malloc(s);
}
```

In my example, I use a static global struct to store the number of calls for each functions and the sum of size at each call. The wrapper code is but in a small lib that you can link with your test code (or, if you diretly print statistic, you can use LD_PRELOAD.)

The result is interesting, for example, you said that fopen doesn't use malloc, using that kind of tricks, you can see that it's false. On a 64bits recent linux system, for example, I got one malloc call for 568 bytes when using fopen ([edit] of course the free is done in fclose.)

Comment: GNU libc already has built-in hooks for malloc/realloc/free/etc, so you don't have to it by hand. It also provides built-in allocation debugger through [mtrace()](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Tracing-malloc.html#Tracing-malloc).